# Lua настройка рабочего окружения, написание программ в Linux

Tags: linux, ide, lua

Был ли у кого нибудь опыт написания графического приложения с использованием языка программирования Lua?

Хочу написать простой текстовый редактор для работы с файлами, но информации по данному языку мало.

Я знаю что lua хорошо совместим с СИ и графическую оболочку можно написать на одной из библиотек.

Как грамотно настроить рабочую операционную систему для работы с lua скриптами?

Прошу всех кто писал прикладные программы на lua откликнуться.

Нужны источники с примерами или информация.

Благодарю за ответ.

Всем добра!

Comment: Сфокусируйте вопрос на какой-то одной конкретной проблеме. Да и в общем-то непонятно, в чём у вас в принцпе проблема — у вас не получается сделать что-то из перечисленного?

Comment: Здравствуйте, ну если кратко. Мне не понятно как lua скрипты работают с графикой. Какую технологию  использовать для linux. Например создание кнопки и получение ответа... Нужен аналог, пример или статья, информация. Есть примеры как пишут скрипты в играх, но как сделать gui программу я пока не нашел.

Comment: Если вас интересует gui, то уберите из вопроса упоминания web и рабочего окружения, чтобы вопрос был сфокусирован на одной проблеме

Comment: А вообще поиск даже по этому сайту сразу находит упоминания [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/) например

Comment: посмотрите ещё на Love2D и Glu